# What route do I add to map to an API controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I've added an ApiController to my asp.net core 2.2 app and the async calls from the UI are not matching.

Here are my routes in Startup.cs.

```
app.UseMvc(config =>
{
    config.MapRoute(
        "Api",
        "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
    );

    config.MapRoute(
        "Default", 
        "{controller=App}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

Here is one of the javascript functions that's making various GET requests to the API controller.

```js
function clearAllFilters() {
  $.get({
    url: "/api/GridFilter/ClearAllFilters",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {
        console.log('filters cleared');
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the API controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class GridFilterController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] FilterFields = {
        // Bunch of strings, omitted for brevity
    };

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ClearAllFilters()
    {
        foreach (string column in FilterFields)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue(column, out byte[] savedJson))
            {
                HttpContext.Session.Remove(column);
            }
        }
        return Ok(true);
    }
```

Why doesn't asp.net match this? My url is /api/controller/action which seems like it matches the first route that's mapped in startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're [mixing Conventional Routing and Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#mixed-routing-attribute-routing-vs-conventional-routing):

> Actions are either conventionally routed or attribute routed. Placing a route on the controller or the action makes it attribute routed. Actions that define attribute routes cannot be reached through the conventional routes and vice-versa. **Any** route attribute on the controller makes all actions in the controller attribute routed.

The following call from your example configures a conventional routing template:

> ```
> config.MapRoute("Api","api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
> ```

However, you've configured `GridFilterController` to use attribute routing by using a routing attribute (`[Route(...)]`):

> ```
> [Route("api/[controller]")]
> [ApiController]
> public class GridFilterController : ControllerBase
> ```

To access the `ClearAllFilters` action from `/api/GridFilter/ClearAllFilters`, you have two general options:

1. Change the attribute routing template to:

   ```
   [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
   ```

   This means the name of the action will be included as part of the route, which is similar to the conventional routing template you've set up.
2. Remove the `[Route(...)]` attribute altogether. However, this isn't ideal, as you'll also have to remove the `[ApiController]` attribute because that [*requires* attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#attribute-routing-requirement).

Comment: Thanks. I searched and searched through Microsoft's documentation but somehow did not pick up on the detail that you must use attribute based routing for api controllers. I went with option 1 as you recommended. Works great now.

Comment: I've added a docs link to the answer re the attribute routing requirement.